# Use UP caret in ActionBar to go from Activity to Fragment - Android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I've been researching all day/night for a solution, but it seems there are lots of options to go from an `Activity` to a `Fragment`, but none are working for me on S.O. In practice, I am in an `Activity`, and I want to use my app logo in the `ActionBar` to click it and then return to a `Fragment`. This `Fragment` is the "parent class" of my `Activity`, meaning there was a button in the `Fragment` I clicked that took me to my `Activity`.

But I can't get all the code snippets I've seen to work.

I have put this in my `onCreate()` of my `Activity`:

```
// Shows the up carat near app icon in ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I also included this in my `onOptionsItemSelected()` method of my `Activity`:

```
// Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The result is that I see a "back button" carat (as shown below), but when I click it nothing happens. I'm supposed to go back to the `Fragment` I came from. FYI, my `Fragment` class actually extends `Fragment` (not `FragmentActivity`). My `Activity` extends `ActionBarActivity`, so I am looking for an answer that will work for Android 4.0+. Also, my `Fragment` does not need the same instance (necessarily) when it is returned to. It only has buttons on there, so a new instance is fine, if it gets created, upon returning.

**Thanks for your help!!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One small line was needed: `finish()`. Since the `FragmentManager` pops off one item in its backstack, by using `fm.popBackStack();`, it still needs some sort of action to go to the previous fragment. Adding `finish()` enabled the current `Activity` to end. The line in context:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code I had above was correct and is needed too, to make it all work. Now, I am able to navigate to my `NavigationDrawer` fragment, click a button there to go to an `Activity`, then press the navigation UP caret to return to my `Fragment` at anytime. This was tested successfully on a Samsung Galaxy5 phone.

One thing that you do not read about in the *Navigating Up with the App Icon* section of the [ActionBar Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) is that since you are using a fragment to return to, you cannot use their `<meta-data>` tag instruction to *specify the parent activity in the manifest file*, because you are not returning to an `Activity`! But rather a `Fragment`. So a workaround had to be achieved by using `FragmentManager`.